# can't add permission BILLING in XDK

Tags: android, cordova, intel-xdk

I try to add a permission on the corodva build apk file to enable in-app products. I tried to add permission from the project tap -- permission. But each time I upload the apk I can't find the billing permission on the uploaded apk.

I always get that

```
Required permissions 8 permissions 
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
android.permission.CAMERA
android.permission.FLASHLIGHT
android.permission.INTERNET
android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
android.permission.SEND_SMS
android.permission.VIBRATE
```

I add the permission

```
BILLING
```

and/or

```
com.android.vending.BILLING
```

but with no result.

One more thing is that when I open the intelxdk.config.android.xml I found this line

```
<preference name="android - permission" value="BILLING"/>
```

please note that there is a space in the "android - permission"
and I can't change that as this file are auto formatted when I build for android.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: when you add 'com.android.vending.BILLING' its also with spacing?

Comment: yeh i add it from the project tap Cordova setting ... i cant add it manually as you see in the .xlm file there is this note <!--This file is generated by the Intel XDK. Do not edit this file as your edits will be lost.           -->

Comment: hmm its sound like a bug, but you can try to edit the apk directly?

Comment: Have you looked at In App Billing Plugin? https://github.com/poiuytrez/AndroidInAppBilling/blob/master/v3/README.md

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<preference name="android-permission" value="Billing> />
```

Note that your **name** contains spaces but the [documentation](https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/articles/cordova-for-android-build-options) doesnot.

Comment: Yeah i have already notes that but i cant edit this file as it's rewrite by the builder just before the code are submitted by the new cordova build system